# Specifications for SQL "comment" data type

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Where can I find specifications for the SQL data type called "COMMENT". I am interested to know more about this.

[image: SQLDataTypeComment]

Comment: Maybe it was a User Defined Data Type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I it is not sql server data type, it is user defined data type.

Which is nothing else but: `CREATE TYPE COMMENT FROM VARCHAR(500)`

Get all user defined data types like: `SELECT * FROM sys.Types WHERE is_user_defined = 1`

or check them in object explorer:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is not a TSQL datatype. It looks like a user defined datatype. It is all CAPS. You can query user defined types.

```
select * from sys.types
where is_user_defined = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The user defined datatype founded on existing data type. Indeed, it can be considered to be nothing more than an alias for the base types already found in SQL server.

**Syntax**

```
CREATE TYPE <TYPE NAME>
FROM <BASE TYPE>
[SCALE]
[NULL | NOT NULL]
```

In your case it might be

```
CREATE TYPE COMMENT
FROM NVARCHAR(MAX) NULL
```

**For more information:** https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-user-defined-data-types/